# Hide DropShadow from Hints

Tags: delphi, tooltip, shadow, delphi-10-seattle

In my application i want to use hints to show additional information.

It looks like this:

[image]

I noticed that Firefox shows hints without the dropshadow:

[image]

My research on google only brought me to questions about adding a dropshadow (XP days) and not removing them.

So my question is:
How can i remove the dropshadow from hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just create your own hint window class inheriting from THintWindow, remove CS_DROPSHADOW in CreateParams and then set vcl to use your class instead of default.

```
TMyHintWindow = class(THintWindow)
protected
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;

procedure TMyHintWindow.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.style and not CS_DROPSHADOW;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOldHint := HintWindowClass;
  HintWindowClass := TMyHintWindow;
  // FOldHint is type of THintWindowClass;
  // If you like to reset hint window to its original value you just set it back to FOldHint
  // HintWindowClass := FOldHint;
end;
```

Comment: So this is for vcl. I tend to forget about fmx.